# How can I fill a WPF ListBox with a custom subclass of ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies

I have a made a Subclass of ListBox and ListBoxItem in WPF because I want to add some custom Dependency Properties to both controls. I have used this example:[To override the container rendering of the ListBox, to fill the Box with my Custom ListBoxItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581934/have-a-databound-wpf-listbox-generate-subclassed-listboxitems)

The code to make this happen looks like this:

```
        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        CustomBoxItem container = new CustomBoxItem();

        return container;
    }
```

This works great but my question is: do I have to set all the dependency properties by hand? Because in my CustomBox.Xaml I cannot set Dependency Properties in the root  tag. I would like to do this in the xaml:

```
<UserControl mycustomdp="SomeValue">
```

I know I can set the DP in the sample code above by doing this:

```
container.mycustomdp = "SomeValue";
```

But when I want to set bindings it's going to be much less elegant than setting the properties in XAML. Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like the wrong thing to do. How is your custom ListBoxItem so special that you cannot achieve the same with the standard ListBoxItem and a custom Template?

Comment: I would like to add Dependency Properties to the listboxitem

Comment: what kind of DependencyProperties? what for?